# Android Studio , Google MapFragment - mapv2

Tags: android-studio, android-maps-v2

i know there are many question about this but it's about 2 days i work on this and i was  unable to find a correct solution (i'm new to android). I need to create an app that can handle a map and draw some markers. I can't even show a map on my device :( Nexus4

This is what i have done :

i copy the google-play-services.jar into my libs dir and change the gradle.build to handle the new library :

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar' , 'libs/gcm.jar', 'libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

i already signed my app and enabled the mapv2 api and change the android manifest like this :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

...

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

<permission
        android:name="com.metu.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.metu.xxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="SIGNATURE_HERE -> ^_^"/>
...
```

my java class looks like this :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class AtmActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_atm);
    }
}
```

my xml layout looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

compiling this code is ok but when i tap on the button to show the activity the app crash :(
This is the error log :

```
06-16 13:34:30.957      523-535/?                              E/qcom_sensors_hal: hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 0
06-16 13:34:39.716  28726-28726/com.metu.xxx            E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
    at com.metu.xxx.AtmActivity.onCreate(AtmActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Somebody can help me ?
or maybe can link a good how to to solve this ?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english :)

UPDATE :

it seems i completly wrong with this.

following this tutorial and everything went fine : http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79

(there is a part missing in the copy files, you need to copy the jar and the settings to the libs file of the module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference google play services project and not only the jar.

Comment: i have found a how to import a google play services as a library here : http://android.rzeszow.net/?p=79 and it works, build fine but when i open the map is blank ... i can only see the bottom right button + and - ...

Comment: find it! it was a problem with my api key :)